# How can I remove "Powered by Odoo" on odoo 8.0 (OpenERP)?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

How can I remove "Powered by Odoo" on odoo 8.0 (OpenERP) ?
[image: Refer the image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First go to your Odoo web module and open below file.

```
addons => web => views => webclient_templates.xml
```

Now find this tag `<div class="oe_footer">` and put it comment like.

```
<!--div class="oe_footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank"><span>Odoo</span></a>
</div-->
```

Hope this will solved your problem.

Comment: It's recommended that you don't change the original file, instead, overwrite it in your module, that way you don't break your code when upgrading or the like :)

Comment: @NehemiasHerrera just read your comment five time but did not get what you mean..  What is the difference between changing the original file and overwriting?

Comment: @njoshsn, he is talking about making of a new custom module. I think, you are changing other path of module. checkout your sever addons path and than please make a related changing on it.

Comment: @njoshsn, I meant exactly what Odedra clarified :) when you have to modify system files, it is recommended to do so by overriding those files with another file from a custom module, not modifying the original file, modifying your original file may break you app when upgrading odoo. in the end, those views files get stored in the database, your custom files can overwrite those tuples in your database.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend QWEB template to remove it, create `template.xml` under `static/xml/` containing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="web.menu_secondary">
        <t t-jquery="div.oe_footer" t-operation="replace"/>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can Inherit web module and apply below code.**

```
<template id="menu_secondary_replace" inherit_id="web.menu_secondary" name="Submenu">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_footer']" position="replace">
                <div class="oe_footer">
                    Powered by <a href="your website name" target="_blank"><span>Your String</span></a>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using jquery adding this script on document ready:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".oe_footer").remove()
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: on which document will one add this?

Comment: @njoshsn you can add this snipped in this file `addons/website/static/src/js/website.js`

Comment: This did not work for me below is how I inserted the code to the file you suggested


      `     (function() {
          "use strict";

            /* --- Set the browser into the dom for css selectors --- */
         $(document).ready(function(){
     
       document.getElementsByClassName("oe_footer").remove();
      alert("Removed");
    }); 
    var browser;
    if ($.browser.webkit) browser = "webkit";
    else if ($.browser.safari) browser = "safari";
    else if ($.browser.opera) browser = "opera"; `

Comment: @njoshsn open in browser firebug and go to scripts tab and see all the scripts included and insert this only `$(".oe_footer").remove()` on one general script from there in document ready function

Comment: @njoshsn you can add the script to `/web/static/src/js/views.js`

Comment: Tried that as well but nothing changed... is there anything else I am  to do after I change the script??

Comment: @njoshsn if `$(document).ready` function exists paste only `$(".oe_footer").remove()` else add ` $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".oe_footer").remove()
    });`

Comment: With all due respect this is not the answer.. it not helpful at all

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

1. Log in as administrator and "Activate Technical Features",
   if not activated this is done by going to Settings => Users => Users => (Select your Administrator user name. The default is Administrator.) > Edit > Usability > Technical Features > check the box (active), click Save.
2. Go to Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views.
   In the search box, next to "(filter icon) Active", type "Login Layout" and hit enter to search.
   There will be one search result. (View name: Login Layout. View type: QWeb view.) Click to open it.
3. Click Edit.
4. Search for "web.menu_secondary" and edit it as needed.
5. Click Save.
6. Log out and in again things will have changed.

[Debranding Odoo backend - Wayback Archive April 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150427064409/http://odoo.guide:80/debranding-odoo-backend/)

Comment: @user568021 are you sure you logged out after making all the 5 steps you can also try to clear the cache of the browser this worked for me on odoo 8

Comment: Which version are you using and the environment as well

Comment: @njoshsn Hi... I've rolled back to the edit made that fixed your list indentation and a couple of grammar issues - not sure why you rolled it back yourself, but the edit does make your post more consistent and readable...